# Android-Firebase authentication and Facebook conflict error

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'`
for firebase authentication, I have also integrated facebook sdk separately.
But when I compile this code, its give me menifest error or tool:replace for android:supportsRtl and android facebook.application_id

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId@value value=(@string/facebook_app_id) from AndroidManifest.xml:120:13-52
>       is also present at [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:13-60 value=(@string/facebook_application_id).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:118:9-120:55 to override.

Comment: why don't you remove your facebook sdk dependency from your gradle build file? You can use the facebook sdk which come with the firebase ui

Comment: how to access sdk from firebase-ui

Comment: well, it should be visible in your dependency view of your project. you can access all dependencies which comes with your integrated dependency in your gradle build file like all other dendendies

Comment: i want to remove those dependencies i wan to use facebook sdk, not firebase for facebook, how to remove facebook-sdk from firebase-ui

Comment: well, please post your Gradle Build file

Answer (score 1):

add

```
<resources>
<!-- ... -->
<string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">CHANGE-ME</string>
```

replace Manifest.xml

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_application_id" />
```